# How to keep updating google map using intent?(android Java)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3, android-intent

How do I keep updating the map while tracking the gps?

`getmap()` is being calling when a button is clicked.

```
public void getMap() {

   //if (a != 101.717026 || b!= 3.002034) {

   Toast.makeText(TestdbActivity.this,newaddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                       Uri.parse("http://http://maps.google.com.my/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr="+newaddress+"&daddr="+params1+""));
   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
   i.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
   startActivity(i);
}
```

updategps function:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    a = location.getLongitude();
    b = location.getLatitude();
    String message = String.format("New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s", a, b);
    Toast.makeText(TestdbActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    newaddress = b+","+ a;
    return;
}

public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    Toast.makeText(TestdbActivity.this, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(TestdbActivity.this,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(TestdbActivity.this,"Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Can I make a `while` loop? If use `while` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Well the normal solution for displaying a map if you want it to update would be to put a mapView in your own activity rather than making your activity start the maps application.  Do you have a good reason for doing it this way?  doing it the way you are at the moment your application of course moves down the activity stack as soon as you start the MapsActivity and you loose control.

Once registered with the location manager onLocationChanged will be called regularly so you just update the map in there.  Of course with a mapView in your own activity you can set this up to just be automatic.

[Here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/) is the page about the maps api.
[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) is the tutorial referenced from the above.

Comment: ok i think i get ur point. then are what tutorials do u recommended for me?as i am still a beginner for android java. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have added a link to the tutorial as well.  You need to read the other stuff as well and get a suitable api key.  The debug one will do to start with but you do need to do this bit yourself as the key is specific to you.